# what does "get to take home the school’s best broomstick over spring vacation" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The giddy boy couldn’t believe it—he’d actually won the school lottery
> and would get to take home the school’s best broomstick over spring
> vacation.

Does 'to take home the best broomstick over spring vacation' mean to take it *for the duration* of the spring vacation and to return it afterwards? Or does it mean to take it *during* the spring vacation for good (forever)?

Or maybe it depends on the context (which I, sadly, don't have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means he was allowed to take the broomstick home either (1) at one or more separate times during the spring vacation, or (2) for the whole vacation. If he was to be away from school during the whole vacation period, meaning (2) is the right one.

> over
>
> preposition
>
> DURING
> during something, or while doing something:
>
> *I was in Seattle over the summer.*
>
> *Shall we discuss it over lunch/over a drink?*
>
> *They took/spent an hour over lunch (= their meal lasted an hour).*
>
> *It's fascinating to watch how a baby changes and develops over time (=
> as time passes).*

[Over (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over)

Answer (score 3):

Many schools have an incentive for children where a pupil, perhaps as a reward for outstanding work, can take home the school pet for the duration of the school vacation. I remember when I was a child having a hamster or a gerbil or something like that in our home for a couple of weeks. The pet would be returned to the school at the end of the vacation.

I don't recognise the source of your quote but it seems to be a play on this tradition, only with a broomstick, not a pet. Is the quote from Harry Potter or something similar? In stories about wizards they often have flying broomsticks.

Comment: Close guess, It's from "The Unofficial Harry Potter Vocabulary Builder".